# Trying to add a nav bar to the top of the page, keeps moving main content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BOQaZP

When I try to add a navbar it keeps pushing the images to the right.  I want a hamburger menu, then to the right of it I want list items side to side next to each other. I want the images to stay centered on the page both horizontally and vertically.

I've tried

```
header{
  display: flex;
}

.menu{
  display: flex;
}
```

but this pushes the images over to the right. 
The only thing that comes to mind is floats and clears, but I've heard that's outdated.

Comment: Don't make body a flexbox. When it's removed, the results are ok.

Comment: My thinking behind that was to try to keep the images centered on the page.  Now when I adjust the height of the nav the images move up. Do you know what is going on?

Comment: Welcome to so! What else have you tried? This looks like a basic css solution. I would recommend trying to edit your `.navbar{  }` in your .css to make it do what you're describing, then do the same to your images. I'll bet there are some great examples online. In general, you don't just want other people to solve your problems on S.O., you want some help after you can't seem to find or don't understand a solution.

Comment: I have added position: absolute to the wrapper div with a top: 20%.   Then a height of 70px to the .navbar.    I would like for the images to respond to fit the window size when resized, would a media query be the way to do this?

Comment: It's less of wanting someone to solve my problems, and more of ensuring I'm using best practice